# '$common' is undefined - AJAX Control Toolkit error in asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an asp.net web page with a ModalPopupExtender and I'm getting the following error when the page loads:

> Message: '$common' is undefined
>   Line: 2
>   Char: 2784
>   Code: 0
>   URI: https:///ScriptResource.axd?d=RtZliaGPxbVTibdn1QCLLFCYmkQJLzmVdEg8YVHOawz2u0jp4PvhsrY5Kg6-rtio9wXKnnE88B3dPvlDZPsA89Ul_--ULFJ0EwbU35JI9_Fa4mL5XwLwQEomAqEfSv6eluWku9SSc-q_lmfPgC4bQA2&t=ffffffffbad362a4

The popup works fine on one production web server (running Windows 2003 R2) but fails on the other (running Windows 2008 R2).

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Are you using the standard ASP.NET ScriptManager in this page, or are you using the ToolkitScriptManager?  See here for more info: http://codes.codedigest.com/FAQ/34-What-is-the-difference-between-ASP-Net-AJAX-ScriptManager-and-Ajax-control-ToolkitScriptManager--.aspx

Comment: I'm using the ScriptManager.  I'll take a look at ToolkitScriptManager.  Thanks.

Comment: This can also happen if other javascript errors exist on the page, or if somehow a script is not being downloaded, so use firefox + firebug to check that all the scripts are making it (no 404, and that you can find $common in one of the downloaded scripts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to ToolkitScriptManager and the error has gone away.  Thanks David Stratton.